# Failure to run WSL internal command from powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-task-scheduler

I need to run WSL internal command from powershell script triggered by task scheduler on user logon. OS: Windows 11 22H2.

```
# waiting for wsl.exe to appear
# before adding this I was getting errors about no command wsl
# probably something about how MSIX packages work in Windows
while (-Not (Get-Command wsl.exe))
{
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
}

while (-Not (wsl.exe ip a))
{
    Write-Output $LastExitCode
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
}
```

Result in script logs is:

```
1
1
1
...
```

After logon the script runs infinitely. WSL commands are available, I can write in a console `wsl.exe ip a` and get the result and `$LastExitCode` is 0. But the script is still running until I stop the task in task scheduler. Somehow the script can not get access to WSL.

When I run the script from admin console, it works fine.

Task options in task scheduler:

- When running the task, use the following user account: `<my account>`
- `(*)` Run only when the user is logged on
- `[x]` Run with highest privileges
- Triggers: at log on: `<my account>`
- Actions: Start a program: powershell.exe -file "`<path to the script>`"

"Run with highest privileges" is necessary because the script needs to run `netsh` commands.

How can I fix it to run WSL command?

In Windows 10 the same script with the same task scheduler settings works fine.

Comment: If you want to run a linux command as an admin then put "sudo" Infront of the command.

Comment: I'm confused by `Get-Command wsl.exe`: This command's output implies  whether the `wsl.exe` executable is _discoverable via `$env:Path`_, and such a test doesn't make sense in a _loop_, because it is either true for a given user or not. If not, it won't become true over time, and you should just make your script fail. If the intent is to wait for someone else (another task) to launch a `wsl.exe` _process_, use `Get-Process wsl` rather than `Get-Command wsl.exe`

Comment: @jdweng wsl command is not running at all. `ip a` does not require sudo.

Comment: @mklement0 before I added the cycle waiting for wsl.exe to appear, I got errors like "no executable found". I suppose that can be because of MSIX installation of WSL in Windows 11.

Comment: @SelivanovPavel, but how does the installation method factor into this? From what I can tell, the command discovery is purely based on the entries in the `$env:Path` variable, which should be invariant for a process (unless explicitly changed).

Comment: @mklement0  wsl.exe is "app execution alias", seems that it appears dynamically depending on user settings.

Comment: You may be right that that makes a difference, though I still find it puzzling, given that these app execution aliases are implemented via NTFS _reparse points_, which - loosely speaking - are like symbolic links; but perhaps because additional logic beyond simply pointing to a different file-system item _statically_, that's where the problem  may arise. Another thing you could try - and I don't know if it'll help - is to simply _try invocation_ until it succeeds, instead of relying on `Get-Command`.  Have you tried running your script _interactively_ in an elevated session?

Comment: @mklement0 Interactively from elevated session the script works fine. From task scheduler it infinitely fails. It already tries "wsl.exe ip a" until success. wls.exe appers, but it does not work with WSL if started from task scheduler

Comment: Ah, I see. So the problem isn't that `wsl.exe` never _appears_, it is that, once it has appeared, _calling_ it never works. Needless to say, that is puzzling too. Have you examined the error messages resulting from the failed calls? Is it PowerShell itself that fundamentally fails to _create the process_, or does the process launch and itself then reports an error?

Comment: @mklement0 I failed to find a way to get any error messages: Set-PSDebug -Trace 2 and Start-Transcript -Path my.log reveal nothing. Just can see the exit code = 1 with $LastExitCode.

Comment: Try saving to a file with an explicit directory path or look for `my.log` in `$env:SystemRoot\System32`, the default working dir. for scheduled tasks (placing log files there is best avoided). In the simplest case, do something like `wsl.exe ip a *>>%TEMP%\my.log`

Comment: @mklement0   I was getting the log successfully, it's that wsl command didn't post any output, just failed with exit code 1.

I've found the solution, look at my answer. I just  have no idea why it didn't work and why it started working that way )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a **known problem** as of this writing - see [GitHub issue #9231](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9231) - and it affects the following scenario:

- Your WSL version was installed *from the Microsoft Store* (either via the application or via `winget.exe`).
- You're trying to launch `wsl.exe` *from session `0`*, i.e. the hidden `services` window station in which services run.

  - This, in turn, implies that you've chosen a logon method that involves a *service*, which applies whenever the `Run whether user is logged or not` option in the Task Scheduler GUI (`taskschd.msc`) is selected (which also applies when you run in the context of a privileged system account such as `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`).<sup>[1]</sup>

---

You've found the ***workaround*** yourself:

- Run your task with the `Run only when user is logged on` option selected, for which you have two options:

  - Configure your run-at-logon task to run *as a specific user*, i.e. only when that user logs on.
  - Configure your run-at-logon task to run whenever a user from a *given group* logs on, say `Users` (to target all users).
    Note that this assumes that all accounts in the group have at least one WSL distro installed in the context of their account.
- The workaround is effective whether or not `Run with highest privileges` is checked.
- The price of this workaround is that your task invariably runs *visibly* at logon (a console window will open that auto-closes when the task exits).

---

With the workaround in place, my informal tests suggest that you do *not* need to wait for the `wsl.exe` executable to become available in your script (and even the first `wsl.exe ip a` call succeeds); to be safe, a loop - albeit just a single one - is retained in the following reformulation of your script:

```bash
do {
  # Note: 
  # * To allow the logs to capture *stderr* output too, add 2>&1  
  # * The `catch` block triggers only if `wsl.exe` can't be found.
  #   Exit code `2` is used to signal that fact, but you can set any nonzero one.
  try { wsl.exe ip a } catch { $global:LASTEXITCODE = 2 }
  if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) { break }
  $LASTEXITCODE   # Output the nonzero exit code.
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
} while ($true)
```

Note:

- You should *not* apply the [`-not`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Logical_Operators) operator / direct to-Boolean coercion to external-program calls in an effort to test their process *exit code*:

  - In PowerShell, doing so coerces a command's *output* to a Boolean (`$true` or `$false`), which in the case of external programs applies to their *stdout output*, and only the *absence* of stdout output is coerced to `$false` (which `-not` inverts to `$true`).
  - However, you cannot infer the success status of an external-program call from the presence or absence of stdout output: there may be such output even if the process exit code ultimately signals failure (nonzero value) and, conversely, a process may succeed (`0`) *quietly* (without stdout output):

    - Case in point: `while (-not (wsl.exe true)) { }` is by definition an *infinite loop*, because the `true` shell builtin *only* sets an *exit code*, without producing *stdout output*, so that `-not (wsl.exe true)` is always `$true` (it is in effect the same as `-not $null`).
- The only reliable way to determine success vs. failure of an external-program call is to examine its process *exit code*, which in PowerShell requires the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode), as shown above.

---

<sup>[1] It seems that it isn't strictly about session `0` per se, because running with the following built-in system accounts, which also run in this session, doesn't *fail*, but complains about no distros being installed in the context of these accounts: `LOCAL SERVICE` and `NETWORK SERVICE`. In other cases you get *errors*: Trying to run as a a specific user with `Run whether user is logged or not` selected, results in error `The file cannot be accessed by the system`; trying to run with the built-in `SYSTEM` account results in error `Access denied`.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! Too bad I can not do dozen upvotes for it )

Comment: So if I uninstall WSL and install a downloaded version not from MS Store or via winget it will work? I'm suspecting it won't because it looks like it's intentionally sabotaged to not work when a user is not logged in by inclusion of UI components. [I forget how I learned this unfortunately but I tried some things and arrived at that conclusion.]

Comment: @AdamD., given that the GitHub bug report talks about the Microsoft Store version being affected, there's at least a chance that downloading via a different mechanism works, but I don't know for sure. If there are GUI components present even then, as you suspect, it may indeed don't work.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: it did not work in this configuration before, then I switched it back and forth, and now it does. I don't have a slightest idea why.

So: WSL successfully runs from scheduled task with [x] "Run with highest privileges" if the task also has setting

(*) Run only when user is logged on

Described failure occurs if the task has setting

(*) Run whether the user is logged on or not

[x] Do not store password may be on or off, task still fails.

Comment: @mklement0  I was expirementing with it a lot. So it looks it was not working at the moment of writing answer in that configuration, then I switched it, then I switched it back and now it works.

I also found a very strange thing:

`while ( -Not ( wsl.exe ip a ) ) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500; echo $LASTEXITCODE ; }` exits immediately, as it should.

But

`while ( -Not ( wsl.exe true ) ) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500; echo $LASTEXITCODE ; }` runs forever printing 0.

The more I dig, the less I understand.